# AddAdoptionDetails' is not a valid metadata type for type filtering operations. Type filtering is only valid on entity types and complex types

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I'm getting this error AddAdoptionDetails' is not a valid metadata type for type filtering operations. Type filtering is only valid on entity types and complex types

My model class  has some properties and I copied my model class shown below.

```
public class AddAdoptionDetails
{
    [Required]
    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Please enter at least 3 characters")]
    public string firstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string lastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\.-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", ErrorMessage = "E-mail is not valid")]
    public string email { get; set; }

    [Compare("email", ErrorMessage = "The email and confirmation email do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmEmail { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(4, ErrorMessage = "Please enter at least 3 characters")]
    public string address { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid phone number")]
    public string phone { get; set; }
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a value bigger than {1}")]
    public int tearm { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string animals { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string adoptionDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Amount value bigger than {1}")]
    public string totalAmount { get; set; }

    public bool isActive { get; set; }

    public List<AnimalAdaptionDetails> animalAdaptionDetails { get; set; }
}
```

My controller class:

This is my controller  class I've used LINQ joins, I need to convert the list to *strongly typed model view*

```
List<AddAdoptionDetails> Query = _context.AnimalsAndBirdsAdoptions.Join(_context.UserDetails, animal => animal.DonarDetailsId, usr => usr.Id, (animal, usr) =>
             new
             {
                 firstName = usr.FirstName,
                 lastName = usr.LastName,
                 address = usr.Address,
                 email = usr.Email,

                 AnimalsAndBirdsId = animal.AnimalsAndBirdsId,
                // DonarDetailsId = animal.DonarDetailsId,
                Term = animal.Term,
                 PeriodOfAdoption = animal.PeriodOfAdoption,
                 isActive = animal.isActive
             }).Join(_context.NameOfAnimalsAndBirds, adoption => adoption.AnimalsAndBirdsId, animal => animal.Id, (adoption, animal) =>
                 new
                       {
                           adoption,
                           animal
                       }).GroupBy(x =>
                       new
                       {
                           x.adoption.firstName,
                           x.adoption.lastName,
                           x.adoption.address,
                           x.adoption.email,
                           x.adoption.Term,
                           x.adoption.PeriodOfAdoption,
                           x.adoption.isActive
                       }).
                      Select(g =>
                      new
                      {
                          totalAmount = g.Sum(e => e.animal.Amount),
                          g.Key.firstName,
                          g.Key.lastName,
                          g.Key.address,
                          g.Key.email,
                          g.Key.Term,
                          g.Key.PeriodOfAdoption,
                          g.Key.isActive,

                      }).OfType<AddAdoptionDetails>().ToList();
```

Comment: The error is because of `.OfType<AddAdoptionDetails>()`. What exactly are you expecting from that code? The result of the query is not `AddAdoptionDetails`, but anonymous type, so it won't work even with LINQ to Objects query. Probably you should change the last `Select` to project to `new AddAdoptionDetails`,

Comment: @IvanStoev I need to convert the result list to strongly typed model view

Comment: `OfType` is not for converting. In LINQ, Convert == Select

Comment: hello @IvanStoev thanks, how do I convert anonymous result list to strongly typed model view. is their any suggestion link article  to convert Generic List<anonymous type > to Generic List <Classname>?

Comment: By using the proper `Select` method. That's basically what I'm saying in my previous comments.

Comment: sorry @IvanStoev ,I didn't get you. please help me . can you please rewrite my LINQ query

Comment: I wish I can. But it's impossible because I don't have all these classes used by the query.

Comment: @IvanStoev yes, can you try to write last line of  ``` select ``` query